# How to sort a list by time and similarity?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, similarity

I would like to sort a list of objects. Each object has a property `year` and a property `name`. The Java List needs to be sorted.

**Class:**

```
public class Record {
    String name;
    int year;
}
```

As an example, assume that we have the following records (already ordered by the attribute year):

**Objects/Records:**

```
2000 Paul
2000 Peter
2000 paul
2001 Paul P.
2001 micael
2001 jessica
2002 Michael
```

Because there are multiple records within one year, I want to sort by the name, such that similar names appear as a group. Thus, after sorting, the list should look as follows:

**Desired Output:**

```
2000 Peter
2000 Paul
2000 paul
2001 Paul P.
2001 jessica
2001 micael
2002 Michael
```

`jessica < micael` in 2001 because in 2002 there is a record Michael (which matches micael with a similarity metric such as edit distance).
Furthermore, `Paul P. < jessica` because in 2000, we also have paul records. And `paul records > Peter` because in 2001 there is also a Paul P. record.

I am aware of similarity metrics such as Jaro Winkler, Levenshtein and so on and these also work as expected in my code. The issue is how to order this List regarding the two dimensions and how to implement this with a comparator (is it even possible with a simple comparator?)

Comment: Have the associated class implement the `Comparable` interface and include your sorting implementation in the overridden `compareTo` method, and then use `Collections#sort` to sort a list of them. This sort of question is asked on a daily basis..do a little bit of investigative work first before asking a question.

Comment: What is the logic that determines that `2000 Peter` is listed before `2000 Paul`?  Without some definitive logic you can put into words, I can't see this going anywhere useful..

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you, I explained this now in the initial question. 2000 Peter is listed before 2000 Paul because in 2001, there is also a record Paul P. (which matches Paul if I use a string similarity metric). Thus, the order is not alphabetic. It depends on the following/previous records.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of solutions to this kind of problem. You've got a comment suggesting that you implement comparable. However for multi dimension sort, I prefer to have two separate comparators which I use to sort the list in sequence. With a stable sort this has the benefit of ordering your items as desired. You sort by the most important property last, so you would want to sort by name, then by year. Alternatively (and more efficiently), you could use `com.google.common.collect.Ordering`. This is in the `Guava library` (a great one) and is basically a super comparator. Here is how you might use it:

```
Comparator<MyObject> compareByYear = ...
Comparator<MyObject> compareByLevenshteinDistance = ...

Ordering<MyObject> orderByYear = Ordering.from(compareByYear);
Ordering<MyObject> compoundOrdering = orderByYear.compound(compareByLevenshteinDistance);

Collections.sort(myList,compoundOrdering);
```

Note that you can create orderings directly. I created them separately to illustrate that an Ordering is an enhancement to a Comparator. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I tried to implement this as you described it. However, there is an issue regarding the "compareByLevenshteinDistance" comparator. The comparator returns a negative value, zero or a positive value. The similarity score is [0, 1], i.e. I can decide when I have to return 0.  In the other cases, it is not clear what to return (if I return stringA.compareTo(stringB), it will be ordered alphabetically, but this is not necessarily correct. The order depends on the records before and after.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Collections.sort()` if you're using a `List`

For instance:

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();

    test.add("one");
    test.add("first");

    Collections.sort(test);

    for (String output : test) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }
```

Would output "First" then "one".

Answer (score 0):

Use Collections.sort(list, comparator) and implement a suitable comparator.

Since you don't provide the details of your class, the answers can also only be at a meta-level.

Comment: Thank you, I added some more information and explained further the ordering of records.